# Pytest --cov doesn't report files without tests

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage

I have a directory containing `a.py, b.py, test_a.py`. when I run `pytest --cov --cov-report=xml` in the same directory, in the xml generated file I can only find the report for the a.py file. however, I need to have 0% coverage for the b.py too.
I have already tried adding `__init__.py` to the directory.

Thanks.